# Why is Ionic 3 apk build with '--prod --release android' giving Google playstore error that apk was signed in debug mode?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic3

My Ionic 3 app build is not accepted by play store anymore. I am sure there is nothing wrong with the certificate and signing process. I had made several releases previously, last one being in July 2018.

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.11.3
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Linux 4.15

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/sebinbenjamin/Android/Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

I build with this command

$ ionic cordova build  --prod --release android

Unsigned release apk is being generated at

> /home/.../app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk

I sign with the following commands

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ~/app.keystore ./platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk aliasname
```

and then do zipalign

```
zipalign -v 4 ./app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk android-signed-release.apk
```

This process was working until very recently. Now I get this error from Play store.

> "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug
>   mode."

I'm sure that I have signed and that the apk is in release mode (as given by the file name android-release-unsigned.apk). Please help.

Comment: When you generate `android-release-unsigned.apk` (in the build process) and `android-signed-release.apk` (in the signing process), make sure that the creation dates of both files are recent (to certify that they were generated in the commands you have just run, otherwise you could be using some old APK generated in another build). Also, the keystore is the same file that you used when you generated the APK the last time (when you uploaded to the Play Store successfully)? Are you using the same alias/password?

Comment: I've deleted all apk's in the build output and it's the correct one which is being signed. I am using the correct keystore, alias and password. It's totally strange.

Comment: It's really strange. Unfortunatelly that error has very few results when I google it. Have you tried to contact their support (Play Store)?

Comment: No. I guess I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checks on Play store recently got a bit tighter.
To check for debug certificates the Play store looks at your certficate and checks if it has `"CN=Android Debug"` in it.
You can check this yourself, use a command like:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

Comment: Yes I have CN=Android Debug. I should have taken care to create the certificates properly. Now I think I need to submit new one for app signing.

Comment: New certificates with proper CN and other fields are working. Certificate expiry should be at least 25 years. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing build manually to release production. You can do by this way.

1. Create a new file called "`release-signing.properties`" and paste the below lines (Replace with your storePassword, keyPassword, keyAlias)

   ```
   target=android-26
   android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
   storePassword=yourstorePassword
   keyPassword=yourkeyPassword
   keyAlias=yourkeyAlias
   storeFile=../../resources/keystore.jks
   ```
2. Place your keystore file at the following path

   ```
   /YourProject/resources/keystore.jks
   ```
3. Place your file "release-signing.properties" at the following path

   ```
   /YourProject/platforms/android/release-signing.properties
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   ionic cordova build android
   ```
5. And then:

   ```
   ionic cordova build android --prod --release
   ```

you can get production build at the following path (You can use this build to google play store)

```
/YourProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk
```

Comment: I was doing that previously, but messed up somewhere and abandoned it. Now I do commands manually to keep things simple and safe.

But right now I don't think that is related to the issue.

Comment: app/platforms/android/release-signing.properties gets deleted every time I run ionic cordova build  --prod --release android

Comment: for me its working fine. The above steps that I am following to get build production build still now